# Extract db details from AWS secret manager throws an error - Python

Tags: python, aws-sdk

I am using the below Python code to extract a database details from the password manager but keep on getting the same error 'Unable to locate credentials'. What am I doing wrong?

```
import boto3  # Required to interact with AWS
import psycopg2
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

secret_name = "X"
region_name = "X"

session = boto3.session.Session()

client = session.client(
    service_name='secretsmanager',
    region_name=region_name
)

try:
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=secret_name
    )
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
        print("The requested secret " + secret_name + " was not found")
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
        print("The request was invalid due to:", e)
    elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
        print("The request had invalid params:", e)
else:
    # Decrypted secret using the associated KMS CMK
    # Depending on whether the secret was a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated
    if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
        secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
    else:
        binary_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary']

user = secret['username']
password = secret['password']
db_name = secret['dbname']
host = secret['host']

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='host',port='5432',database=db_name, user=user, password=password)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the AWS Credentials to interact with the AWS API, otherwise you get that `Unable to locate credentials` error.

There are different ways to configure the credentials, so just check this [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) and choose the one that best fit your needs.